# How to Sort a List of objects based on another List of same type by a particular property

Tags: java, list, algorithm, collections, java-8

How could I sort `Employee` `list1` based on `list2` by `name` property?

In addition, we need to maintain a list1 of unordered elements

*Code:*

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SortEmployee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> list1 = Stream.of(
                        new Employee("Zach","Boston","Massachusetts"),
                        new Employee("Alex","Atlanta","Georgia"),
                        new Employee("Jijo","pleasanton","California"),
                        new Employee("Sai","Decatur","Texas"),
                        new Employee("Yohan","Cumming","Atlanta"),
                        new Employee("Agni","sula","Maine"),
                        new Employee("Bajan","Duluth","Ohio"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Employee> list2 = Stream.of(
                        new Employee("Alex","Atlanta","Georgia"),
                        new Employee("Sai","Decatur","Texas"),
                        new Employee("Musa","Fremont","California"),
                        new Employee("Zach","Boston","Massachusetts"),
                        new Employee("Bajan","Duluth","Rhode Island"),
                        new Employee("Khan","Kalan","Ohio"),
                        new Employee("Jijo","pleasanton","California"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("##### List-1 ####");
        list1.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("##### List-2 ####");
        list2.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Employee Object :

```
@Data
public class Employee {
    String name;
    String city;
    String state;
}
```

*Expected output:*

```
List1= 

 - Employee{name='Alex', city='Atlanta', state='Georgia'},
   Employee{name='Sai', city='Decatur', state='Texas'},
   Employee{name='Zach', city='Boston', state='Massachusetts'},
   Employee{name='Bajan', city='Duluth', state='Ohio'},
   Employee{name='Jijo', city='pleasanton', state='California'},
   Employee{name='Yohan', city='Cumming', state='Atlanta'},
   Employee{name='Agni', city='sula', state='Maine'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Naive approach

A naive way would be to create `Comparator` using `comparingInt()` by the logic for retrieving the indexed of the element with the matching name. And then apply `sort()` on the *first list*.

In case if `equals()` and `hashCode()` are not based on the `name` property only, we can create a wrapper class and implement its `equals/hashCode` contract in such a way that only `name` will be taken into account during comparison.

And then based on the `list1` and `list2` generate two lists `EmployeeWrapper` objects (the code below is incomplete and provided only to illustrate the idea).

```
public class EmployeeWrapper {
    private String name;
    private Employee employee;
    
    // getters, constructor, equals/hashCode
}
```

```
Comparator<EmployeeWrapper> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(wrappedList2::indexOf);

wrappedList1.sort(comparator);

List<Employee> sortedList = wrappedList.stream()
    .map(EmployeeWrapper::getEmployee)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it would be terribly inefficient to iterate over the *second list* multiple times. To be precise, time complexity would be **O(m * n log n)** (where `n` - number of elements in the first list, `m` - the size of the second list).

#### Storing indices in the Map

Since the positions of the elements in the second list don't change, we can index them in a single pass through the list and store it in the *map*. And then generate a *comparator* based on this *map*.

The time complexity would be **O(m + n log n)** (*it means the impact of the second list far more moderate*).

```
public static Comparator<Employee> compareByName(List<Employee> base) {
    
    Map<String, Integer> indexByName = getIndexByName(base);
    
    return Comparator.comparingInt(employee ->
        indexByName.getOrDefault(employee.getName(), Integer.MAX_VALUE)); // employee that have no matching pair will be grouped at the end of the resulting list
}

public static Map<String, Integer> getIndexByName(List<Employee> list) {
    
    Map<String, Integer> indexByName = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        indexByName.putIfAbsent(list.get(i).getName(), i);
    }
    return indexByName;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Employee> list1 = // initialing the list

    List<Employee> list2 = // initialing the list

    Comparator<Employee> comparator = compareByName(list2);
    list1.sort(comparator);

    System.out.println("##### List-1 ####");
    list1.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("##### List-2 ####");
    list2.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

In certain conditions, this code can be optimized further.

For instance, if there would be no duplicated names, it's possible to make it run in a *linear time*.

Comment: Is `compareByKey` should not be called `compareByName` ?

Comment: @BenoîtFraikin Thanks, mended. I've simplified the answer to make it more digestible, but didn't change the name. My initial intention was the following: generic method `compareByKey()` expects a collection of objects of type `T` and a `keyExtractor` function `Function<T,K>` that allows to obtain the property by which object should be compared. There is no much difference in the amount of code, but it shifts the focus from the algorithm to the implementation details.